# CSVHelper - Limitations on columns number or data dimensions

Tags: .net, export-to-csv, csvhelper

Are there any limitations (such as columns number or data dimensions or file .csv max size)?

It seems like if limits are exceeded, the row content is escaped with double quote (") at the beginning and at the end of the row.
So just one entire row, instead of a list of cells.

Comment: Not as far as I know.  What limit are you reaching where it is quoting the entire row?

Comment: Can you provide an example where this is happening?